# npm run <script-name> is failing

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-run

I want to build React project as per environment like development, staging and production.

below is snapshot of scripts section inside package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start development": "REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "start staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts start",
    "start production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts start",
    "build development": "REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts build",
    "build production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

So as per scripts, 'build development' should build project for development environment.
Now as i run following command in project home directory by specifying environment, ( staging builds for staging env)

```
npm run 'build staging'
```

below shown error is displayed and command exits

```
> testapp@0.1.0 build staging
> REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts build

sh: 1: /tmp/build: not found
```

Interesting thing is that, the command runs perfectly fine on other systems and creates build folder without any issues but it is throwing error on my current system.

All of my systems are running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Guys any idea about what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding ***cross-env*** as dependency and changing scripts to use _ instead of space as shown below resolved the issue

```
"scripts": {
    "start_development": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "start_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts start",
    "start_production": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts start",
    "build_development": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts build",
    "build_production": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Now the following command runs on all platforms without any issues

```
npm run build_staging
```